# YOLOv4 annotations saves dimensions in a [0,1] float interval

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

This is from an annotations file for an image:

```
0 0.6142131979695431 0.336 0.467005076142132 0.392
```

The first `0` is the class label. `0.6142131979695431` and `0.336` are the x and y coordinates of the bounding box. `0.467005076142132` and `0.392` are the width and the height of the bounding box. However, what I don't understand is why the x, y, width and height are in a [0,1] float interval. Someone told me that it is a percentage, but a percentage relative to what?

For example, I am writing software that builds a synthetic dataset. This is one training image that I have produced. It has the bounding boxes around the objects that I want to detect.

[image]

The bounding boxes wrap the Wizards and Ubuntu logos perfectly. So, how can I annotate them like the format above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The width/height in YOLO format is the fraction of total width/height of the entire image. So the top-left corner is always (0,0) and bottom-right corner is always (1,1) irrespective of the size of the image.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115874/how-to-convert-bounding-box-x1-y1-x2-y2-to-yolo-style-x-y-w-h) for the conversion of bounding box (x1, y1, x2, y2) to YOLO style (x, y, w, h).

[image]